# Is there any gmap’s api function to concatenate address string from AddressDetails structure?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I’am using Google Map’s GClientGeocoder for reversing map coordinates into string address. Exactly as shown in google’s example here http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#geocoding_reverse

But, I would like to remove LocalityName (place.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.Locality.LocalityName) from place.address and have the address string without any LocalityName.

The straight way will be join all AddressDetails elements, excluding LocalityName. However order of the structure elements in final string representation is depends from geographical location.

For example:

Order for Australia city:

ThoroughfareName + “, ” + LocalityName + “ ” + AdministrativeAreaName + “ ” + PostalCodeNumber + “, ” + CountryName

Order for Russian city:

CountryName + “, ” + PostalCodeNumber + “, ” + LocalityName + “, ” +ThoroughfareName

Moreover PostalCodeNumber was not supplied in AddressDetails for the last example.

Please, help!

Answer (score 2):

Get the LocalityName and make a new string without it. As LocalityName is buried in an unknown way within the JSON structure, you need to go through the whole AddressDetails recursively until LocalityName is found. Example:

```
function findLocalityName(item) {
  for (key in item) {        
    if (key == "LocalityName") return item[key];
    else if (item[key] instanceof Object) return findLocalityName(item[key]);
  }
}

var place = response.Placemark[0];
var localityName = findLocalityName(place.AddressDetails);          
var noLocalityAddress = place.address.replace(localityName, '');
```

Working example:

http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=6da11815a8a7435cc971acc9cebe99f4732fc5d0

Click anywhere in the map to show full address, LocalityName and fixed address.

This could use some minor refinements, i.e. if you click "Redfern St." in the example, it will remove the street name instead of the locality name, because the street name is the same as the locality!

Comment: Unfortunately there are some (not rare) cases when given approach will not work.  
For instance when **LocalityName** match the part of the street address or city or even country.  
`
Full Address:Steinalpl 6, 8694 Steinalpl, Austria  
LocalityName:Steinalpl  
No Locality Address: 6, 8694 Steinalpl, Austria  
orig latlng:47.739323,15.556641  
latlng:47.7483495,15.5527866  
Status Code:200  
Status Request:geocode  
Accuracy:8  
Country code: AT  
`
Currently I don't see any solution for this problem.   
But I give you +1 for best intentions :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned in the last paragraph. But I left solving that as an exercise to you :)

For example, you can remove the last appearance of the word in the string instead of the first, as usually LocalityName is towards the end. This would still fail if LocalityName is the same as the Country (it would remove the country), which I think is more rare.

To solve that, you could check if the word appears at the end of the string, if so, then you remove the penultimate appearance of the word. If it doesn't (country is not the same as LocalityName) then you remove the last appearance.